# Unable to insert entry in a SQL database using pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I just started using python to insert entries into a SQL database. I am able to read values from the database, but inserting gives me an error:

`"('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'."`

This is my code:

```
userName = getpass.getuser()      
queryNewUnit = "INSERT INTO AllUnits (Unit, User, Time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"

curForAdd.execute(queryNewUnit, (userEntry, userName, datetime.now()))
conForAdd.commit()
```

Comment: Generally, variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Try wrapping your column names in square brackets, e.g., `... ([Unit], [User], [Time]) ...`

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you! You're a savior!